# PyOtherSide, debugger/breakpoints

Tags: python, debugging, qt-creator, pyotherside

When running a simple PyOtherSide example in QtCreator and setting a breakpoint in python code, is doesn't work (expected).

How do you go about debugging python code used in PyOtherSide?

Also, it appears `print` commands from python doesn't show up in my application output, similar to the way the `console.log` commands in qml do.

Comment: Did you try using a different editor such as PyCharm for debugging your Python code?

Also, it is expected for print not to work in a GUI application (assuming you have a GUI application). What you can do is either switch the print statements with the `logger` module or redirect the print statements to the log.

Comment: Launching the app via the build folder with ./appname will then allow python print commands to output to the terminal there.